# Retrieving Application settings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Say I have the following -

```
<TreeView ...>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <command:DoSomethingCommand x:Key="DoSomethingCommand"/>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="DoSomething" 
                              Command="{StaticResource DoSomethingCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
...
```

DoSomethingCommand needs something from the general application settings. Lets say it is a Save command and needs the directory location to default to.

How do I get this to the ICommand implementation?

Comment: Your command should probably be reading directly from the settings class in this situation without binding to the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it directly in the implementation of the `ICommand` through `Properties.Settings.Default.NameOfTheSetting`, trying to pass it through XAML doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

If you *really* want to, add an xmlns:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:TestSettings.Properties"
```

Then you can bind to it through something like:

```
<MenuItem Header="Some Menu"
          Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},
                                     Path=SomeSetting, 
                                     Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't like using Properties.Settings.Default because it then couples the code to only having a single instance. What happens in future if ever we want two of these windows with separate settings?

Comment: How else are you accessing `Settings`?  Applications only have one (active) instance of their `Settings` class.

Comment: If you need something else, make it a property on your view model, and bind to *that*.  It's the same concept as shown above.

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default` is practically the only way to directly access application settings.

Comment: If I inject the settings object in at the top then i can trivially swap over to passing in a separate settings object if required - say a Properties.SpecialSettings object. I'd far rather inject it in and maintain the flexibility. The ICommands are specific to the TreeView object so it feels like I should be able to reference other context specific to it too.

Comment: If you are injecting it, then you (should) have access to it through a property,.  Just bind to that with the regular data binding mechanism.  The only time you need to do anything special is when you want to bind to the static `Settings` class generated by Visual Studio that belongs to the application.

Comment: The problem is the ICommand does not have access to it. I guess what I will have to do is inject it in and add the ICommands to the resources in the constructor rather than in the xaml.

Comment: If you bind it to the command parameter, the icommand can read it through that. Just bind it to a property on the view model that contains a reference to the injected settings.

Comment: Ah - you're suggesting on the ViewModel. That would work. Although currently i'm passing through the selected object, not the top level view model. I also feel this is a UI only value - so i'm not convinced it belongs in the viewmodel.

Comment: If you have all these special requirements, they really should be listed in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options I can see from your snippet.

1. Deliver the proper property binding via your viewmodel to the `CommandParameter` in your `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. You should qualify to a name i.e. `{Binding FilePath, Mode=OneWay}` which you could declare as either a `string` or a `Path`. The `CommandParameter` would then have it as an object that you can handle via `ICommand.Execute(object parameter)`
2. Reference a static property directly inside the `ICommand.Execute()` method.

Comment: The problem is that the object to act on is already being passed through as the command parameter.

And static seems like a bad idea - What if in future we need two of this userpanel both of which want their own settings?

Comment: Well, project settings in your application properties *are* static. Maybe you are actually referring to 'settings' i.e. properties in your model?